# window.webkitNotifications.checkPermission() Not Working

Tags: javascript, notifications, webkit

When you go into console and try `window.webkitNotifications.checkPermission()`, you receive this error; `TypeError: Cannot read property 'checkPermission' of undefined`

I'm using the latest version of chrome and it was just working the other day. Any ideas to the reason behind this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since ~May 2014, Chrome disabled their own implementation of HTML5 notifications.
Now, if you want to keep your notification code still working - you have to replace Google implementation with standard HTML 5 Notifications code.

Here you have quite good description about Notification in HTML5 - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification

Replace unused Webkit methods & properties and your Chrome will work again with desktop notifications.

Comment: @Vardan
Yes, I used methods from standard HTML 5 Notifiaction implementation and it works now fine.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me.. it think it will help you..

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
// Using https://rawgithub.com/auchenberg/WebNotification.js/master/WebNotification.js as a external lib.

$(function() {

    $('.request').on('click', function() {
        window.Notification.requestPermission(function() {
            alert('Permissions state: ' + window.Notification.permission);
        });
    });

    $('.show').on('click', function() {

        if(window.Notification.permission !== 'granted') {
            alert('Permissions hasnt been granted');
        }

        new window.Notification('This is a test');        
    });    

})
</script>

<button class="request">Request permissions</button>
<button class="show">Show notification</button>
```

The reference URL is.
http://kenneth.io/blog/2013/07/15/the-messy-state-of-web-notifications-in-chrome-safari-blink-webkit/